# Why does it change shape when i apply the scale?

Tags: scale

I just noticed that the scale whas wrong on my canle. So i applyed the scale on it and it went fine. Then when i did the exact same thing on the wax it suddenly became a "muchroom". why does it do that and how do i fix it?[image]
[image][image]

Answer (score 3):

It's because your modifiers act on original mesh scale 1.

Say you have a 1m diameter pipe mesh with 0.1 m thickness with the *Solidify Modifier*.

If you make it 2m diameter (scale it to 2 without applying it), you now have a 2m diameter with a thickness of 0.2m despite the *Solidify Modifier* still showing a thickness of 0.1m. The new scale and thickness are shown in the Viewport, but the modifier shows the values valid for a scale of 1)

And if you now apply the scale, the new thickness would be 0.1m because that's what the modifier is set to.

NOTE:
Scale is for the object and the modifier values are for the mesh. Object is separate from mesh (you can change the mesh that is used in your object anytime)

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Your last paragraph is a bit misunderstandable... it sounds like object scale and mesh are independent from each other, but of course they are not. If you scale an object in _Object Mode_ the mesh is scale with it of course. And in the same way the modifier is scaled. But overall your answer is definitely correct and the solution for her problem.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Try this: get default cube (object 1) and copy it (object 2). now make the mesh of object 2 from Cube.001 to cube. now scale the object 1 and apply it. you will get an error. now on the object 2 change mesh to Cube.001 and apply the object 1 scale and after that change object 2 from Cube.001 to cube. see that the object 2 is now changed in scale?
As you see scale dose not affect the mesh unless it is applied to the mesh. a 1m tall mesh is always going to be in 1m tall mesh in every object even if the object is 10m tall.

Comment: But yes I see what you mean as user expect that what you see is what you get.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that, didn't know I could learn such a basic thing after 20+ years in 3D modeling :D No seriously, I know that. I just wanted to say that this can be misunderstood by users that don't have as much experience. Especially when they are scaling non-multiuser objects they might not get these errors. By the way, duplicating the cube with Alt+D makes the second cube automatically use the same mesh as the first one... no need to switch meshes or anything.

Comment: srry, was trying to clarify what I meant. No assumptions about you were made. but yeah I was going for manual change in mesh cause that way new user would change it manually and see that it is a different thing. it's my 3rd year into 3d and I did not know that 1-2 years ago and I wished I knew that sooner. hence the example.

Comment: thank you so mutch!